# Can not read property 'NullLogger' of undefined (angular/cli 1.4.7)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Today, sudeenly I start getting this error 
**"Cannot read property 'NullLogger' of undefined"**  while trying to add a component ( ng g c abc) in my angular 4 app.  When I searched it on google, people are suggesting that we need to update our cli version to 1.4.10 .  But the question is **why we are getting this error now for all angular/cli version below 1.4.10?**  . I do not want to update my CLI version now.  Does anyone know why is it happening??

Following is my package.json file,

`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "toastr": "^2.1.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/toastr": "^2.1.35",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
  }`

Comment: why negative rating. Is it not worth asking OR to know? when suddenly a working app start showing this error. why angular team force someone to update cli. it should be a choice. NO?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I did following to resolve the issue,

Uninstall @angular/cli globally

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

Uninstall @angular/cli locally

`npm uninstall --save-dev @angular/cli`

clear cache,

`npm cache clean`

install @angular/cli globally and locally again

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

`npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`

All worked after that.

Comment: @edgar mlowe  thanks for correcting the "clear cache" command.

Comment: I needed to do "npm cache clean --force" with an admin level command window.

Comment: using node-v12.14.0-win-x64 which includes npm (since before v8.12), I had to remove (I renamed) c:\Users\myidt\AppData\Roaming\npm for `ng new` and `ng generate` to behave correctly.

Comment: (it started to detect that the project had a different cli version, plus was able to generate a project with the good cli and a component without the 'NullLogger' error)

Answer (score 1):

I received this error also.
The accepted answer unfortunately didn't help me.

So I needed to install the newest version of Node.js. And install CLI again:

> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

After that the the issue was resolved.