# 'NullLogger' of undefined when create new component

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm facing now an error when I create new component

```
ng g componenet testComponent
```

the error is

```
        Cannot read property 'NullLogger' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'NullLogger' of undefined
    at SchematicEngine.createContext (d:\Nodejs Workarea\sherif negm\blur\back-end\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\engine.js:75:39)
    at SchematicImpl.call (d:\Nodejs Workarea\sherif negm\blur\back-end\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\engine\schematic.js:35:38)
    at Promise (d:\Nodejs Workarea\sherif negm\blur\back-end\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\schematic-run.js:77:23)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Class.run (d:\Nodejs Workarea\sherif negm\blur\back-end\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\schematic-run.js:76:16)
    at Class.run (d:\Nodejs Workarea\sherif negm\blur\back-end\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\generate.js:149:33)
    at resolve (d:\Nodejs Workarea\sherif negm\blur\back-end\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:261:20)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Class.validateAndRun (d:\Nodejs Workarea\sherif negm\blur\back-end\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:240:12)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (d:\Nodejs Workarea\sherif negm\blur\back-end\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli.js:140:24)
```

angular -g -v is

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.5
node: 10.8.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.7
@angular/common: 4.4.7
@angular/compiler: 4.4.7
@angular/core: 4.4.7
@angular/forms: 4.4.7
@angular/http: 4.4.7
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.7
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.7
@angular/router: 4.4.7
@angular/cli: 1.4.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.7
@angular/language-service: 4.4.7
typescript: 2.3.4
```

and dependencies in my project are

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angular-sortablejs": "^2.5.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-bearer": "^0.1.28",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "sortablejs": "^1.7.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

this error is being show to me after I have updated angular to 6 and then I downgrade again to previously version 4

please i don't need update angular of my project .

Comment: *ng g componenet testComponent*… should be `ng g component testComponent`? Component is misspelled. Or, is that just a typo in the post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not read property 'NullLogger' of undefined (angular/cli 1.4.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567460/can-not-read-property-nulllogger-of-undefined-angular-cli-1-4-7)

Comment: @R.Richards no it's just misspelled  I have wrote it here

Comment: @R.Richards I have red this answer but I don't need update my project dependencies on less now

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the CLI, and reinstalling the version you are using? Like this: `npm i -g @angular/cli@1.4.5`.

Comment: Yes i tried but all cli not work except @angular/cli: 1.4.10 this worked with me I have upgrade @angular/cli in global and in my project dependence and it's work, i don't know why this version is work @angular/cli: 1.4.10

Comment: @R.Richards thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by upgrade @angular/cli in global and project dependence to @angular/cli: 1.4.10

Answer (score 0):

Below steps worked for me,

> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
>
> npm uninstall --save-dev @angular/cli

clear cache,

> npm cache verify
>
> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
>
> npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest